# jQuery preventDefault in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used `preventDefault` on an element event like this:

```
$('#element').click(function (e) {
    do stuff...
});
```

Now, I have a function that takes an argument already in which I would like to use `preventDefault` but I'm not sure how:

```
<a href="#services" id="services_link" class="services" onclick="sectionScroll('services')">Services</a>


function sectionScroll(id) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '#' + id);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

I tried using return false instead but this caused some flickering when the link was clicked.

How can I add `preventDefault` to the above function?

**EDIT**

My original question was around using preventDefault in a function that has other arguments.  I didn't need to use inline javascript in the end (it was looking like there was no way to avoid it), so this is what I used.  I think it's quite tidy:

```
<a href="#services" class="menu-link">Services</a>


   $('.menu-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var location = $(this).attr('href');
        history.pushState(null, null, location)
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(location).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using inline javascript??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, if you really want to use inline event handlers (wouldn't recommend it though), try this:

```
<a href="#services" id="services_link" class="services"
   onclick="sectionScroll('services', event)">Services</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sectionScroll(id, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.pushState(null, null, '#' + id);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer; the rest of the answers offered are just stating what I already know and mentioned in the question!  While I agree that using inline js is not a good idea (I avoid it whereever possible), sometimes it's required.  I was also curious to know how this could be done when calling a fuction from another function.  I will test this later and mark as the answer if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery, like you are with the other example, to handle the click event:

```
<a href="#services" id="services_link" class="services">Services</a>

$('#services_link').click(function (e) {
    var id = "services";

    history.pushState(null, null, '#' + id);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    }, 1000);

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

This will then allow you to call `preventDefault` on the event.

This is also much better since you will no longer be using inline Javascript and your event logic can all be handled using one method (i.e. jQuery) rather than some of it being in jQuery and some inline.

I would suggest reading "[Why Should I Avoid Inline Scripting?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting)" to get an idea of why you should try to avoid inline scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You could just return false from the event handler:

```
<a href="#services" id="services_link" class="services" onclick="return sectionScroll('services')">Services</a>


function sectionScroll(id) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '#' + id);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false; // note the addition of return keyword in onclick attribute above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the event Handler in **js** itself instead of **HTML**

```
<a href="#services" id="services_link" class="services"
                                       data-id="services">Services</a>
```

/

```
 $('#services_link').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // data-id is a HTML5 data attribute

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        history.pushState(null, null, '#' + id);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

If .on("click") adds "overflow:hidden" to the body or html, the page scrolls anyway to the top, even if you use e.preventDefalt() inside the callback.